# How can I claim an abandoned city?

Tags: simcity-2013

I bought Simcity complete edition from Origin. I also got the Nissan electric car addon and the deluxe edition plus the rest of the downloadable content.

As far as I can tell, I have bought everything possible. I was on the origin app and under the game's extra content, everything is checked.

So in the game, in my region there are several abandoned cities. I tried to claim it but it says there is content that I don't own when the city was created. I don't understand what this is because I have purchased everything.

What's the problem here? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I contacted Origin/EA and the reason why I cannot claim some of the abandoned cities is because there were some free in game content that was available only during a limited time and now it is no more.

For example, the Progressive Insurance building, which is what their support staff told me is missing. The support staff was trying to find and grant me this DLC however it does not exist on their server so there is no way to get it as far as I know. I even downloaded a version of Simcity from torrent and tried to replace the data files but this did not work either and it actually made my existing cities not loadable(I had to revert my changes).

This is very unfortunate but there is no way to claim some abandoned cities unless EA/Origin gets their hands on those limited time DLC and add them to the game